# How to show activityIndicator while pushing to viewcontroller in Objective c

Tags: ios, uiactivityindicatorview

I have used singleton class for activityIndicator.Then i will call that class where ever i want. No problem while loading but loading is not appearing while pushing to other viewcontroller.

```
 - (void)editBtntapped
 {
      [loading showLoadingView:self.view ForSubView:self.view];

      Screen_Participant_Edit *controller=[[Screen_Participant_Edit alloc]init];
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:NO];
      [controller release];

 }
```

loading is the object of sigleton class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to show ActivityIndicator on the MAINWINDOW instead the UIVIewController.

```
- (void)editBtntapped
{
     [loading showLoadingView:appDelegate.window ForSubView:appDelegate.window];

     Screen_Participant_Edit *controller=[[Screen_Participant_Edit alloc]init];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:NO];
     [controller release];

}
```

What you are doing is adding the ActivityIndicator to the previous UIViewController and then pushing new UIViewController. So, the present UIViewController in which ActivityIndicator was placed disappears.

Comment: I tried this activity indicator is coming after the view loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Quite a simple solution, rather than showing activityIndicator in view, add activityIndicator on `UIAlertView`.
Hope this helps solve your issue..

Comment: This is a good solution.But i cant implement this now because am in the end of my project i cant change in all the classes also i have used custom alertview and custom activityindicator